# Text justification stretching the verbage

Tags: html, css

I have applied text justification to some verbage. Here is a link to the content:

[Click here](http://jobrangers.com/newtemplate/flatone-default/verbage.html)

If you look, sometimes inside the verbage the words are stretched to fit the container. It looks wrong because there is spacing inbetween the words that expands larger than the default.

**How do I remove this abnormal spacing**

Comment: as a general rule you should add the relevant code, to your question.

Comment: That's exactly what text justification is supposed to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p.verbage {
    text-align: left;
}
```

instead of

```
text-align: justify
```

*justify* aligns the text left and right by introducing extra spacing between words.

Comment: In a very few situations, adding a negative `word-spacing` would decrease the space between justified words.

Comment: @HashemQolami true but dangerous in my opinion, as it might overlap words when the spacing between them is already little.

Comment: That's true, it should be used with care. That's why I started my comment with `In a very few situations...`

Answer (score 0):

You don't - that's how full justification works.  If you don't want weird spaces between words, you'll need to live with a ragged right or left margin and use `text-align: left`,`text-align: right`, or `text-align: center`.